# get entire packate instead of individual line of tcpdump packet using php script

Tags: php

I am using below script to retrieve all my sip packet on 5060 port.

```
$cmd ="tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -i eth0 port 5060";
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
if (is_resource($process)) {
        while ($info = fgets($pipes[1])) {
              flush();
        }
}
```

Most welcome to correct or make better code of above.

Looking for help for below three points.

1.if i `print_r($info)` it gives me individual each line of entire packet instead of that ,I am expecting to get entire packet into `$info` variable.

2. I tried to find already developed libraries which may help to retrieve all sip packet on realtime.but i don't get any libraries so please share with me if you know anyone already.
3. Is it good to connect mysql database inside while loop to store packet into database and then close mysql connection ?

Comment: `fgets` reads line by line, so you should be concatenating or appending somewhere. If you want the whole thing you can use `stream_get_contents`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for reply but it won't work in above code .Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: What won’t work? I presented two options

Comment: I mean stream_get_contents it's not working to get whole thing. fgets is working fine in my case.